# If $V$ is a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^1$ and $\vec v \in V$ and is nonzero, how do I prove $\mathbb{R}^1$ is a subspace of $\text{span}({\vec v})$?

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-writing

Now, I know that I'm supposed to somehow show how it is that $\vec v$ spans $\mathbb{R}^1$, but this is precisely what I don't know how to do.

I know that if $\mathbb{R}^1$ is a subspace of $\text{span}({\vec v})$, then any $k\vec v$ will be able to attain any $\vec r$ in $\mathbb{R}^1$. But how exactly do I write this down?

The point of this proof is to eventually prove that any nonzero subspace of $\mathbb{R}^1$ has to be $\mathbb{R}^1$ itself.

Comment: False if $v=0$.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy thanks, I had forgotten to say it was nonzero

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see that you understand the bigger picture, namely "any nonzero subspace of $\mathbb{R}^1$ has to be $\mathbb{R}^1$ itself". This means, of course, that $\vec{v}$ cannot be $0$.

So how should we express this? In short, we rely on the more general result that:

- A subspace $U$ of a vector space $V$ (where $\dim V = n$) has dimension $d \in \{0,1,\dots,n\}$ .
- If $U$ is a subspace of a vector space $V$ and $\dim U = \dim V$, then $U = V$.

Understanding the first is as simple as seeing that any subspace $U$ is spanned by the basis of $V$, so there exists a way to reduce it down to a basis of $U$. This implies that any subspace of $\mathbb{R}^1$ either has dimension $0$ (the trivial subspace) or dimension $1$.

Now, we look at the second result. One can easily show that any linearly independent set of vectors of size $n$ in a space of dimension $n$ is spanning. Thus, consider the basis of the vector space $U$. It has length $n$ and is linearly independent, so it spans $V$ (and thus is a basis for $V$). Since the same list of vectors is a basis for $U$ and $V$, $U = V$.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but say in the case that $U$ is $\mathbb{R}^2$ and $V$ is $\mathbb{R}^3$, how are we able to establish $U$ is spanned by the basis of $V$ if we're forced to take out a component from the basis of $V$ to span $U$? Thanks! (Or do I have to find a way to restrict that to $\mathbb{R}^1$)?

Comment: There is a lemma (look it up, it's everywhere online) that says that (a) any linearly independent set can be extended to a basis and (b) every spanning set can be reduced to a basis. Clearly $V$'s basis spans $U$, and $U \subseteq V$, so $V$'s basis spans $U$ and we can apply the lemma.

Comment: Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

If $v \neq 0$ then any $x \in \mathbb R$ can be written as $cv$ where $c=\frac x v$ so $x$ belongs to $span (v)$.

Comment: I assume that $c$ here is a scalar and $\frac{x}{v}$ is the division of the components of $\vec x$ and $\vec v$?

Comment: @shintuku $V$ is supposed to be  a subspace of $\mathbb R$. Vectors here have only component so there is no difference between vectors and scalars. You can think of $\frac x v$ as the ratio of the first components, if you wish.

Comment: Thank you for the help!