# Problem with: if $V$ is subspace of $\mathbb{R}^1$ and $\vec v \in V$ is nonzero, then any vector $\vec x \in \mathbb{R}^1$ can be written $k \vec v$

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-writing, proof-explanation

I was attempting to show that the only nonzero subspace of $\mathbb{R}^1$ is $\mathbb{R}^1$ itself, and someone told me that it can be proven showing how if a subspace $V \in \mathbb{R}^1$ has a subspace $\text{span}(\vec v)$, then any $\vec x \in \mathbb{R}^1$ can be written $c\vec v$ if $c = \frac{x_1}{v_1}$, where $x_1, v_1$ are the first and only components of $\vec v, \vec x$.

First: how come $c\vec v$ (where  $c = \frac{x_1}{v_1}$) is defined if we have not yet established that $\vec v$ and $\vec x$ pertain to the same subspace? Couldn't these component vectors have distinct bases?

Second: it might sound like an odd question, but if any $\vec x$ *can* be written as $c\vec v$, how do we know it *will* have such a form? Isn't this statement too weak to complete the proof?

Comment: You have approved an answer to the same question . You could have asked for more details there instead of posting  a new question. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3582582/if-v-is-a-subspace-of-mathbbr1-and-vec-v-in-v-and-is-nonzero-how-do

Comment: I understand this as a different question concerning the particular way to understand a method of proof to another question. I have done my research prior to posting this question and have taken into account your answer in the question you mentioned, which has sparked this second question. Thank you for the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured out what was up:

To put in other words what my original problem with the proof was: it seemed to me to be circular: if we define $\vec x$ in terms of $\vec v$, are we not assuming what we need to prove? For this would only be possible if they were, at the beginning of the proof, in the same subspace, but whether or not they are in the same subspace is precisely what is in question.

The reason the proof works is: indeed, $\vec v$ and $\vec x$ do not pertain to the same subspace at the beginning of the proof, but we are **not** defining them in terms of one another. $c$ is the piece that allows us to go from $\vec v$ to $\vec x$.

So, suppose we begin the proof with $\vec v \in V$ and $\vec x \in \mathbb{R}^1$ and say that they pertain to vector spaces over the field $\mathbb{R}$ (if $V$ is a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^1$, then it follows from the definition of a subspace that $V$ is a vector space over $\mathbb{R}$). The first thing we do is declare some constant $c = \frac{x_1}{v_1}$. This is fine because $x_1$ and $v_1$ are scalars and not vectors, and rigorously speaking, this operation happens only within the field $\mathbb{R}$ and we are not assuming any shared subspace between $\vec v$ and $\vec x$. Now:

$$ c\vec v = [cv_1] $$
$$ = [\frac{x_1}{v_1} v_1] $$
$$ = [x_1] $$
$$ = \vec x.  \ \ \square.$$

In other words, in order to prevent circularity, one must declare $c$ and go from $\vec v$ to $\vec x$ before declaring that any $\vec x$ can be written as $c\vec v$.

It would be, however, incorrect to take $\vec v$ and $\vec x$ to be in the field $\mathbb{R}$: they indeed behave very similarly to elements of $\mathbb{R}$, but rigorously speaking they belong to the vector space $\mathbb{R}^1$. Division (or multiplication) of the components of two vectors in not defined in a subspace, but only in a field, and this is a required operation in order to perform the proof. And we cannot do the whole proof only within a field, because we need $c\vec v$, which is only defined in a vector space. Supposing we ignore the vector form and perform the proof only within a field, we have not proven our proof holds for vectors or subspaces, even if they seem to behave similarly.

This was implicitly going on in the proof and is perhaps obvious to some more experienced, but it was non-trivial to me unless I put it in the above format.

Answer (score 0):

> First: how come $c\vec v$ (where  $c = \frac{x_1}{v_1}$) is defined if we have not yet established that $\vec c$ and $\vec x$ pertain to the same subspace? Couldn't these component vectors have distinct bases?

Since $V \subseteq \mathbb R^1$, we can just treat both $\vec v$ and $\vec x$ as vectors in $\mathbb R^1$. In fact, for the proof, we don't have to think about subspaces or bases at all - they're red herrings that don't really add any value.

---

> Second: it might sound like an odd question, but if any $\vec x$ *can* be written as $c\vec v$, how do we know it *will* have such a form? Isn't this statement too weak to complete the proof?

I don't know what distinction you're trying to make here. A given expression can have multiples forms (for example, I can express "$1$" in many forms: as "$7 - 6$", as "$\sin^2 \theta + \cos^2\theta$", or as "$-e^{i\pi}$"). I *can* express $1$ as $7 - 6$, and this also means that it *will always* have such a form.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! That clears it up for the second part. For the first part: your answer makes sense, but what I don't understand is: isn't it beforehands a consequence of our proof that we can treat both $\vec v$ and $\vec x$ in the same way? Otherwise to me it feels coincidental that they can be defined in terms of one another. You've said that all this happens since $V \subseteq \mathbb{R}^1$ (as the definition from the definition of subspace?), I'll look into these properties and get back to you.